# is symfony system wide?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

i have a directory with some .php files in it...do i need to install symfony in that directory so that i can run symfony commands from that directory?? i tried: pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com

and got:
Channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is already initialized

the i tried: pear install symfony/symfony

and got:
WARNING: configuration download directory "/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/pear-build-download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir to avoid this warning
Cannot install, php_dir for channel "pear.symfony-project.com" is not writeable by the current user

how do i fix this please? must i run it as sudo??
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well, Symfony is "system-wide" if installed through PEAR (like you are trying to do).

Now it is recommended by the manual to do a "standalone" install through SVN. See http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony

As well, the sandbox will bring a "standalone" installation of Symfony (you will have to be in the project root directory to be able to run the `symfony` commands)

**EDIT**

Example of quick install using SVN:

```
mkdir /path/to/symfony
cd /path/to/symfony
svn checkout http://svn.symfony-project.com/tags/RELEASE_1_4_0 .
```

but it should be better to follow the manual and configure the external SVN sources.

Comment: thank you.. i ran sudo pear install symfony/symfony and it installed the latest symfony verion in another project directory and not in the directory i was in...i read the link and also agree that i want each project directory to have its own symfony.... so how will i install symfony in the project directory i am in please? i am new to all this and dont know how to go about it...thank you

Comment: The page of the manual I've linked (http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony) explains all those installation steps in detail. Some help with SVN if you need: http://www.froihofer.net/en/students/svn-intro.html

Comment: thank you  i will read through it again...just one last thing please? i have now symfony 1.4.11 installed in the one project directory i need to revert back to version 1.4.2 how will i go about doing this??  must i just redo the steps in the link and have the version as 1.4.2??? thank you

Comment: You should try `svn checkout http://svn.symfony-project.com/tags/RELEASE_1_4_2 .` or set `symfony http://svn.symfony-project.com/tags/RELEASE_1_4_2` into SVN config file.

Answer (score 0):

I run servers where I have applications that use different versions of symfony simultaneously.  I found it much easier to deal with the SVN checkout than the PEAR insteall.

So what I've done is do an SVN checkout of each revision that I need
into it's own folder.  In my case i check them out to

```
/usr/share/symfony/(version)
```

Then I configure the ProjectConfiguration.class.php to reference whatever version is needed, using the line:

```
require_once '/usr/share/symfony/1.x.x/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
```

If I need to switch to a different symfony version, I can just change that config.
That is, assuming all my code is compatible with that version